# Angular JS: HTML in $scope throws jshint error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to include html tags in my model, here is a simple case of including `b` tags:

```
 .controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {


        $scope.oneAtATime = true;

        $scope.groups = [{
            title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
            content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1"
        }, {
            title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
            content: "<b>Dynamic Group Body - 2</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit nobis nihil eaque, et quam similique tempore nam modi iusto nesciunt."
        }];

        $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

        $scope.addItem = function() {
            var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
            $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
        };

    }
]);
```

And, in the html I have `<div ng-bind-html="group.content"></div>`

I shows up in the HTML as bold, as I want, but when Grunt runs, jshint fails "aborted due to warnings".  If I remove the `b` tags, it works.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

At first I think you have used `<div ng-bind-html="group.content"></div>` inside ng-repeat, if no your program will not worked, second please provide us that warnings, it will help to understand what is going on.

Thanks :)